# Join onto other table where there is no foreignkey relationship

Tags: python, django, postgresql, inner-join

I have one Django model with with "some_id" and many other models with "some_id" as primary key.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    some_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    [...] # more fields


class ModelB(models.Model):
    some_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)

    [...] # more fields



class ModelC(models.Model):
    some_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)

    [...] # more fields
```

How can I annotate a ModelA queryset with a boolean field if a row exists in ModelB/ModelC etc

```
------------------------------------------
| name     | some_id   | has_b   | has_c |
-----------------------------------------
| John     |    1      | True    | False |
------------------------------------------
```

Do I need to use ".extra()"? or some database [expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/)

I cant change the model/table to add the foreign key relationship.

Comment: Please don't do this. You can make it a `some_id = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)` in your models, or simply use model inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this with an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

ModelA.objects.annotate(
    has_b=Exists(ModelB.objects.filter(some_id=OuterRef('some_id'))),
    has_c=Exists(ModelC.objects.filter(some_id=OuterRef('some_id')))
)
```

That being said, if the `some_id`s of `ModelB` and `ModelC` always refer to a `some_id` of `ModelA`, then it is better to use a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) since this guarantees referential integrity, and makes it more convenient to use the ORM.